# When I try to export my project as runnable jar file I see this error

Tags: java, swing

Can you help me to exporting this project as runnable jar file?

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);

        JCalendar calendar = new JCalendar();
        getContentPane().add(calendar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

I got this error message if I want to export my project as jar file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press `OK` and the JAR file is created. The message is just a warning to let you know that the licenses allow you to repackage.